# Android: How to fade out search / home / menu / back buttons?

Tags: android, fullscreen

I'm using my Android (Archos 43) only as an extended display in an industrial application. I just need a single program to display data received, and send user inputs by bluetooth. This little program should start directly after booting and should disable (fade out) the android-buttons (search, home, menu and back).

Here's my problem:

I know, there are some applications which can fade out these search/home/menu/back-buttons (like DeskClock or some videoplayers), but how does it work? Just using:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

only disables the titlebar, not the 4 android-buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an android-problem, this is a special feature from my Archos 43 internet tablet.

`androidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="archos.permission.FULLSCREEN.FULL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="archos.permission.FULLSCREEN.FULL" />
```